# In Kubernetes, are podAffinity and podAntiAffinity weights compared to each other? Or independently? What about podAffinity and nodeAffinity?

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes, are `podAffinity` and `podAntiAffinity` weights compared to each other? Or independently? What about `podAffinity` and `nodeAffinity`? Would `podAntiAffinity` outweight the `podAffinity` in the below example? And what if `nodeAffinity` was added to the mix as well.

```
 affinity:
  podAffinity:
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - weight: 50
      podAffinityTerm:
        labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
            operator: In
            values:
            - test-1
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname

  podAntiAffinity:
    preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - weight: 100
      podAffinityTerm:
        labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
            operator: In
            values:
            - test-2          
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

Comment: An interesting question but it does beg the question, if you are being this precise on affinity, are you trying to be too prescriptive on where pods are scheduled? The intended use-case would be something like "I don't want this to run on a GPU node or a RAM node but would perhaps allow it on RAM before GPU". Your example is not making it clear why this would be a good idea since it is like "I want it on a GPU and not on a RAM node" so not sure why the relative weight is relevant.

Comment: @LukeBriner My use case is, I have a constantly running base pool that should have exactly 1 type of each pod, not more or less. And a second, preemtible, high performing pool that can scale from 0 to N, and needs to only be used during high traffic from end users for fault-tolerant traffic, or during certain jobs launched by the data science team.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how you set up your cluster? Cloud provider or on-premise? What Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: @IvanM. I'm using GCP with Kubernetes version v1.21.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All affinity settings for both pods and nodes are weighed the same way if you don't overwrite the default individual weight of 1.

During execution the occurrence of affinity conditions on a node is multiplied by the weight of the condition.

```
pod a has an affinity to b
pod a has an anti-affinity to c

new pod of type "a" to be scheduled
---
node1 runs 3 "b" pods and 1 "c" pod --> affinity score: 2 (3 "b" pods - 1 "c" pod)
node2 runs 1 "b" pod --> affinity score 1: 1 (1 "b" pod)
```

Based on the affinity calculation the pod will be scheduled on node1 despite it already running pod "c" as 3 "b" pods outweigh 1 "c" pod.

In your example the anti-affinity would outweigh the affinity settings if there is a 1:1 ratio of `test-1` to `test-2` on a node. With a 2:1 ratio of `test-1` to `test-2` on a node the (anti-)affinities would cancel each other out.

[Source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/a5489431cfc0598dad421fccd2d713f84bf520bd/pkg/scheduler/framework/plugins/interpodaffinity/scoring.go#L79)

Comment: Oh wow. I hadn't considered that they subtracted, only that they might outcompete each other. Thank you for the great response!